# How to call docusign apis for sending envelopes in node.js?

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have a standard DocuSign account and I want to add an integration key but I am not able to add that key as there is no option to in my standard account to add the key. Further, I want to hit DocuSign API either through nodejs-sdk or postman to create and send an envelope with the use of the template. So, for this what should I do? Can anybody help, please?

Comment: If your question was answered, be sure to accept it below! Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewRoknich still i am struggling with the apis.

Comment: Understood. If you provide some context, I can direct to the most helpful resource.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're just getting started with the DocuSign eSignature API. Welcome! We have a variety of resources that you will find helpful.

I would start here on the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides).

To begin experimenting with our API, you'll first need to [create a demo sandbox account](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/). Within this account, you can provision your own integrator keys. Later down the road, you will follow our "Go-Live" process to transition your integration to our paid, production environment.

Once you have your account created, I would suggest you [check out this quickstart code example.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email)

That should get you started!

Comment: I will not be having an application to pass the go-live process.  I will have a simple script that will use docusign apis to create and send the envelopes using template. Basically, we want to automate the process that's why we are using these apis. So, how will that script pass the go-live process? is there any easy way?

Comment: Hey Amit. For right now, don't worry yourself too much with Go-Live. This process is done once your integration is fully complete. While you are experimenting with our API in the demo sandbox environement, your eSignatures are not legally binding.

Answer (score 1):

You should [create a new developer/sandbox account](https://go.docusign.com/o/sandbox/) to create an integration key. You cannot do that in production.

For node.JS we have a few different resources you can use, the most complete one is our [code example "launcher"](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-node-auth-code-grant) that can be used as a full app to try the code. We also have a [quickstart](https://github.com/docusign/qs-03-node-list-envelopes) that you an use without configuring the API authentication part.

Comment: I will not be having an application to pass the go-live process. I will have a simple script that will use docusign apis to create and send the envelopes using template. Basically, we want to automate the process that's why we are using these apis. So, how will that script pass the go-live process? is there any easy way?

Comment: if you want to use the APIs you need to pass Go-Live. It's not that hard, in fact, we recently made it very easy.

Comment: you can look into PowerForms as an alternative way and not use the API. Might be enough for what you need.

Comment: What is powerforms?

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/features/powerforms

Comment: https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developing-with-docusign-programming-powerforms/

Comment: So, will you pass a single page script also that will be only calling your APIs to create and send the envelope through go-live?

Comment: yes, if it comply with the other go-live requirements. https://www.google.com/search?q=docusign+go+live+requirements&rlz=1C1GCEB_enUS892US892&oq=docusign+go+live+requirements&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2713j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8